# What is the difference between ('a,'b) and ('a*'b)?

Tags: haskell, syntax, tuples, sml

In Haskell we have a tuple type like `(a, b, ...)`. I am trying to read some SML code and I already know that a value `(a, b)` type is `a * b`. But then I saw this:

```ml
type ('a,'b) reader = 'b -> ('a * 'b) option
```

and I understand `('a * 'b) option` - in Haskell it's `Maybe (a,b)`, but what is `('a,'b) reader` ?! Why is not it `('a * 'b) reader`? As I got the syntax of type level tuples is `something * something`.

Comment: It's the declaration of the two type parameters of `reader`. They're two separate parameters, not a tuple.

Comment: @Bergi `type Reader a b = b -> Maybe (a,b)` ... right?

Comment: That's the Haskell equivalent, yes

Comment: `('a * 'b)` is not a pair of types, but is a single type: the product type (the type of all value pairs). Hence, `('a * 'b) reader` would refer to a type `reader` having _one_ type parameter, i.e. `type 't reader = ...`, and choosing `'t` to be the product type `('a * 'b)`. This is not what we have here. Here we have `reader` having two type parameters, so that's a pair of types `('a, 'b)` and not a single (product) type. Haskell notation is, IMO, confusing in using the same syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When introducing a type variable for a type, the parentheses are not necessary.  E.g.

```ml
datatype 'a list = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a list
```

When introducing more than one type variable, we use parens and commas. E.g.

```ml
datatype ('a, 'b) either = Left of 'a | Right of 'b;
```

As noted in comments, this does *not* describe a tuple.

Comment: +1, with the quibble that we don't use the term "generic" here in ML. BTW, this notation is also used when applying the type function: `(int, string) either`. It wouldn't make sense to write `(int * string) either`, because a value of the tuple type `(int * string)` contains *both* an integer *and* a string.